# How to remove possible loss of precision error in java

Tags: java

here is a part of my code where I am getting error:

```
long p=1000000000-size-1;
long j;

for(j=p;j>p-k;j--)
{
    sum2=sum2+sum[j];
}
System.out.print(sum2);
```

I think it is because I am using a `long` variable to define the size of array.
How could I deal with this error

Or if I am wrong please tell me how could I declare an array containing 10^10 elements.

Comment: Do you get any exception or any error message? Please paste the same if you  get  what is sum2 variable type declared?

Comment: yes error message is  error:possible loss of precision int long

Answer (score 0):

Java does not provide a way to create arrays with size bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is about 2*10^9). Also are you sure you have enough memory to store such array? If you want to store array of 10^10 int values, you will need at least 40 Gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Change both the variables to `int.` If the values don't fit into an `int` the code won't work anyway.

> I think it is because I am using a long variable to define the size of array. How could I deal with this error

No it isn't, because you aren't. You can't.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the the maximum array concerns and availability of enough virtual memory:
You have an integer literal `1000000000`, but what you actually want is a long literal `1000000000L`.